# TypeError: decoding str is not supported TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, string, unicode, nlp

i am working on a generating questions from a given text, while encoding and unicoding  the text format i facing an issue. please can any help me out.

```
ww2 = u'''
World War II (often abbreviated to WWII or WW2), also known as the Second World War, was a global war that lasted from 1939 to 1945, although related 
'''
ww2 = unicode(ww2, 'utf-8')

ww2b = TextBlob(ww2)
```

Comment: The error should be part of the question text (not the title). Also, why are you calling `unicode()` ?

Comment: Are you sure this is Python 3? Python 3 doesn't have a `unicode` type, and the name `unicode` is not defined. So in Python 3 this code would raise a NameError (unless you previously defined or imported a function with the name `unicode()`).

Comment: yes its python 3. i need to encode the categorical values into to unique code so i am calling uinicode()

Comment: Well in Python 3 you have the `str` type (for strings of characters, decoded) and the `bytes` type (for strings of bytes, encoded).  To go from `str` to `bytes` use `.encode()`.  To go from `bytes` to `str` use `.decode()`.  As @lenz stated, Python 3 does not define a `unicode` type or method.  To get the error in your title, I think your code is setting `unicode = str`. Unless Python 2 compatibility is critical, do not set or use `unicode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are encoding a string it will be of type  which you cant put into TextBlob() directly. If you are using the encoded value in between before TextBlob() call then you need to decode it first. Also the whole point of BLOB is that they store raw binary strings. So just go ahead and store your stuff directly into your BLOB without encoding them.

Comment: i need to encode it because i am doing further process on it .